# How to bridge small gaps between objects like welding with less faces

Tags: mesh

I am trying to bridge two tubes together like welding.So I applied union to the two tubes and used Remesh modifier with Voxel size of 0.001m. It turns out that there are 5 million faces. It is hard for me to decimate them, which freeze my computer. Am I using Remesh correctly? Or is there a better way to bridge objects other than Remesh? I want a clean object to export for Salome to edit mesh for FEM analysis. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image: ![enter image description here]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for a boolean modifier, on Union mode?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have applied union first before remesh. Union helps to connect the mesh of the two tubes. I want to make the bridging area obvious...like a domain so that I can set material for it.

Comment: Why do you remesh the tubes after you use union? Just use bevel if you need it to look smooth.

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard You kind of remind me. I may not need to use remesh after union. I am looking at welder add-on and shrinkwrap modifier something like that. But still not satisfied yet.

Comment: Shrink wrap? This is getting weird…

Comment: I agree that shrink wrap is not what I want...I am open to other solutions...